# Python tuple assignment and checking in conditional statements

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, tuples

So I stumbled into a particular behaviour of tuples in python that I was wondering if there is a particular reason for it happening.

While we are perfectly capable of assigning a tuple to a variable without
explicitely enclosing it in parentheses:

```
>>> foo_bar_tuple = "foo","bar"
>>>
```

we are not able to print or check in a conditional if statement the variable containing
the tuple in the previous fashion (without explicitely typing the parentheses):

```
>>> print foo_bar_tuple == "foo","bar"
False bar

>>> if foo_bar_tuple == "foo","bar": pass
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 

>>> print foo_bar_tuple == ("foo","bar")
True
>>> 

>>> if foo_bar_tuple == ("foo","bar"): pass
>>>
```

Does anyone why?
Thanks in advance and although I didn't find any similar topic please inform me if you think it is a possible dublicate.
Cheers,
Alex

Comment: Essentially commas when used in assignments are what actually create tuples, not the parentheses. However, __eq__ operator is a function that takes only single argument, and when you pass it values separated by commas, it takes it as passing `arg` rather than passing the tuple `'foo','bar'`. Wrapping in parens forces the tuple assignment operator to happen before the evaluation of `arg`, so it behaves as expected.

Comment: To put it another way, if you think of `foo_bar_tuple == 'foo','bar'` as actually being `foo_bar_tuple.__eq__('foo', 'bar')`, you can immediately see why you need to wrap in parens to make it work

Comment: @aruisdante: Your statement that `foo_bar_tuple == 'foo', 'bar'` is equivalent to `foo_bar_tuple.__eq__('foo', 'bar')` is incorrect. The comparison is happening with just the `'foo'` string (`foo_bar_tuple.__eq__('foo')`, which is `False`) and `'bar'` is left as a separate expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the expressions separated by commas are evaluated before the whole comma-separated tuple (which is an "expression list" in the terminology of the Python grammar).  So when you do `foo_bar_tuple=="foo", "bar"`, that is interpreted as `(foo_bar_tuple=="foo"), "bar"`.  This behavior is described in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists).

You can see this if you just write such an expression by itself:

```
>>> 1, 2 == 1, 2  # interpreted as "1, (2==1), 2"
(1, False, 2)
```

The SyntaxError for the unparenthesized tuple is because an unparenthesized tuple is not an "atom" in the Python grammar, which means it's not valid as the sole content of an `if` condition.  (You can verify this for yourself by tracing around [the grammar](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/grammar.html).)

Comment: Right! Okay thanks for that mate! I will accept as soon as it will let me :) cheers

Answer (score 4):

Considering an example of `if 1 == 1,2:` which should cause `SyntaxError`, following [the full grammar](http://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/grammar.html):

```
if 1 == 1,2:
```

Using the `if_stmt: 'if' test ':' suite ('elif' test ':' suite)* ['else' ':' suite]`, we get to shift the `if` keyword and start parsing `1 == 1,2:`

For the `test` rule, only first production matches:

```
test: or_test ['if' or_test 'else' test] | lambdef
```

Then we get:

```
or_test: and_test ('or' and_test)*
```

And step down into `and_test`:

```
and_test: not_test ('and' not_test)*
```

Here we just step into `not_test` at the moment:

```
not_test: 'not' not_test | comparison
```

Notice, our input is `1 == 1,2:`, thus the first production doesn't match and we check the other one: (1)

```
comparison: expr (comp_op expr)*
```

Continuing on stepping down (we take the only the first non-terminal as the zero-or-more star requires a terminal we don't have at all in our input):

```
expr: xor_expr ('|' xor_expr)*
xor_expr: and_expr ('^' and_expr)*
and_expr: shift_expr ('&' shift_expr)*
shift_expr: arith_expr (('<<'|'>>') arith_expr)*
arith_expr: term (('+'|'-') term)*
term: factor (('*'|'/'|'%'|'//') factor)*
factor: ('+'|'-'|'~') factor | power
```

Now we use the `power` production:

```
power: atom trailer* ['**' factor]
atom: ('(' [yield_expr|testlist_comp] ')' |
   '[' [testlist_comp] ']' |
   '{' [dictorsetmaker] '}' |
   NAME | NUMBER | STRING+ | '...' | 'None' | 'True' | 'False')
```

And shift `NUMBER` (`1` in our input) and reduce. Now we are back at (1) with input `==1,2:` to parse. `==` matches `comp_op`:

```
comp_op: '<'|'>'|'=='|'>='|'<='|'<>'|'!='|'in'|'not' 'in'|'is'|'is' 'not'
```

So we shift it and reduce, leaving us with input `1,2:` (current parsing output is `NUMBER comp_op`, we need to match `expr` now). We repeat the process for the left-hand side, going straight to the `atom` nonterminal and selecting the `NUMBER` production. Shift and reduce.

Since `,` does not match any `comp_op` we reduce the `test` non-terminal and receive `'if' NUMBER comp_op NUMBER`. We need to match `else`, `elif` or `:` now, but we have `,` so we fail with `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 2):

[I think the operator precedence table summarizes this nicely:](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

You'll see that comparisons come before expressions, which are actually dead last.

```
in, not in, is, is not,                  Comparisons, including membership tests 
<, <=, >, >=, <>, !=, ==                 and identity tests

...

(expressions...), [expressions...],      Binding or tuple display, list display,
{key: value...}, `expressions...`        dictionary display, string conversion
```