# Why does if x,y: raise a SyntaxError?

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

I would like to know if there is any reason that the following code raises a `SyntaxError`:

```
>>> if 1,2:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if 1,2:
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Should not `1,2` be interpreted by Python as a two-item tuple (which would then evaluate to `True` when tested by the if-statement)?  The below demonstration suggests that it should:

```
>>> 1,2
(1, 2)
>>> tup = 1,2
>>> bool(tup)
True
>>>
```

Moreover, if you look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement) for Python's if-statement, you will read this:

```
if_stmt ::=  "if" expression ":" suite
             ( "elif" expression ":" suite )*
             ["else" ":" suite]
```

As you can see, it clearly says that the syntax for an if-statement is the `if` keyword followed by an expression.  If I am not mistaken, `1,2` *is indeed* an expression.

Finally, it could be argued that this syntax is useless, so why allow it?  That is true, but the [Zen of Python](http://www.thezenofpython.com/) explicitly says:

> Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.

So why the `SyntaxError`?

Comment: Well... `1==1,2` is indeed an expression, but not what you're expecting I guess. It might return `(True, 2)`.

Comment: @BrenBarn The question is different, and the answers don't apply to this question.

Comment: @delnan: You're right, I thought my answer there included an explanation of the SyntaxError but it didn't.  That question does ask about this kind of SyntaxError as well, though.  Anyway, I edited my answer there, so that answer now answers this question.

Comment: `if 1,2:` gives an error as well. The `==` is not relevant.

Comment: Looks like your use of `==` in the question is confusing the people answering the question... You can get the same error simply with `if 1,2: ...`

Comment: @shx2 - Yea, it appears you are right.  Apologies.  I posted the one with `==` because that was what gave me the idea.  But doing `1,2` will be a lot clearer.  Let me edit my question.

Comment: I've posted a more detail input parsing that leads to this error here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431482/python-tuple-assignment-and-checking-in-conditional-statements/22737335#22737335 .

Comment: @kroolik - That is a very nice answer. +1.  I would have accepted it as the answer to my question if it was not a duplicate.

Comment: Same thing with `while 1,2:` vs `while (1,2):`

Answer (score 1):

It is to do with [how Python scans and interprets expressions](http://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists). You get a `SyntaxError` because Python `if` statements do not tolerate having a comma *between conditions*.

Python reads the statement from left to right, and separates the conditions by a comma unless brackets are explicitly used for separation. This means that your expression is interpreted as this:

```
(1 == 1), (2)
```

So the `tuple` is not separated but rather the two conditions. As commas are not allowed to separate conditions you get a `SyntaxError`. With this in mind, we can know why putting the brackets around the tuple gets a different result. The brackets are explicitly used for separation, so Python can interpret the `tuple` on its own and compare it. In that case there is only one condition- so no error.

Comment: Feedback is welcome! I am always looking to improve my posts.

Comment: While you may *mean* the right thing, your terminology is rather confusing and non-standard, and none of this is particular to `if` as such, only to the kind of expression it requires the condition to be.

Comment: @delnan I am just a student. As long as my answer is correct, feel free to edit it to make the terminology professional and correct. I don't believe that a down-vote is called for here.

Comment: It's not my downvote. And I'm just a student myself ;-) As for editing: I'm really not sure how to fix my complains without essentially rewriting the entire answer. It's not only terminology, it's also that you seem to make this about *conditions* whereas, by the Python grammar, a "condition" is just a `test` which is used in many other contexts too (e.g. default values for parameters and `print` statement arguments).

Answer (score -3):

what you are doing is not what you think.

1==1,2 :you declare two things.  1==1=True and 2.

1==(1,2)=False :they are two different types even.

if 1==1,2:  undoable: not a statement if you think about what I showed you so the (,)comma is not only superfluous it's wrong.

Comment: Write `1 == 1,2` in a interpreter and you will see it's a valid expression. The question is: why doesn't `if` accept this valid expression?

Comment: because its not a testable expression. it's two expressions actually

Comment: The correct answer was given in the question this is a duplicate for and it's a bit more complex, but closely related to the fact that everything is used in the `if` statement.

Comment: then u should already know its 2 expressions automatically packed into a tuple by python